# Reporting income - independent contractor, received no 1099

Tags: united-states, taxes, self-employment, irs, form-1099

I have some stuff from last year that I want to report, I just don't have the information the IRS forms ask for.

I know how much I made and I know what percentage to pay taxes on, but for voluntary compliance purposes I don't know how to report it.

Its freelance/contractor/self-employment work, so does it go on the 1099-misc?

The 1099-misc asks for an individual's SSN or their Employer ID number, and it assumes that they sent a copy of the 1099-misc in as well. This didn't happen and the amounts are over $600 , uh oh.

Anyway, is this the proper form and what do I write down for the SSN? I can't go around asking for social security numbers!

how do people approach this problem

Comment: >is this the proper form and what do I write down for the SSN? I assume that it is a tax-preparation program such as TurboTax that is insisting that you enter the numbers on a 1099-MISC into _their_ form.  That form is never sent to the IRS from TurboTax, nor is it necessary to enter the information on that form. You should be able to enter the amount paid to you directly on a form without having to go through a 1099-MISC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the employer's job to get the 1099-MISC to you.  They should have asked you to fill out a W-9, which would give them your SSN or TIN so that they could file the 1099-MISC if they needed to.

They should have gotten this from you before they paid you a dime.  Now they're late.  You should have received it by the end of January.

As the person receiving the money, it's *not* your job to file the 1099-MISC.

But it is your job to report your income on your tax return, and you can do that without the 1099-MISC.

Comment: He's right you just have to add the number in when you are filling out the form.  Assuming you aren't filing this income as part of a small business it can just be added right in the other income line.  (line 21 of the standard 1040.)

Comment: @Pablitorun Since the OP said it is freelance/contractor/self-employment income, it should go on Schedule C.

Comment: If the OP doesn't have any other freelance work or business expenses they would like to deduct it will functionally be the same.

Comment: "...functionally be the same."  Other income is not subject to Social Security or Medicare tax while income declared on Schedule C income is subject to both the _employer's share_ and the _employee's share_ of Social Security or Medicare tax.  On the other hand, expenses are deductible against Schedule C income but not against Other Income.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can go around asking for social security numbers if you *paid* someone more than $600.  Then you would *file* 1099-MISC.

If someone paid you more than $600: they should ask you for form **W-9** and give you a copy of **1099-MISC** they filed with the IRS.

But when you're doing your tax return, the forms hardly matter.  You just add up your total income and present the final number.  If you have expenses related to the work, or a home office, then file it all on Schedule C and take some sweet deductions for legitimate business expenses.

In short, it does not matter to you if the 1099-MISC arrives.  It's on them, not you.  Of course you could give them a courtesy call just to be helpful.